# Is there a sequence converging to a non-isolated point?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $c \in X$ be a non-isolated point. Is there a sequence $x_n \in X\setminus \{c\}$ that converges to $c$? The answer is no. However, r sufficient condition is for $X$ to be first countable. Is there any separation axiom that coincides with this property? I suspect that it coincides with being a sequential space, or that it is at least implied by sequential spaces (I'd also like to see a proof of this).

For context, I encountered this trying to generalize the following theorem (to $X$ sequential spaces and $Y$ Hausdorff):

> For a set function $f:X \to Y$ between metric spaces. If $c \in X'$, then $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)$ exists iff for every sequence $x_n \in X\setminus\{x\}$ with $x_n \to c$ there exists $\lim f(x_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say that a space $X$ has property ($*$) if whenever $c$ is a non-isolated point then there is a sequence from $X \setminus \{c\}$ that converges to $c$.  I claim that property ($*$) is strictly weaker than being a sequential space.

First, let us see that sequential spaces have property ($*$).  By definition, a space is sequential if every sequentially closed set is closed.  Thus, in a sequential space, if $A$ is not closed then $A$ is not sequentially closed, meaning that if $A$ is not closed then there is some point in $X \setminus A$ that is the limit of a sequence from $A$.  In particular, suppose that $X$ is sequential and $c$ is not an isolated point.  Then $\{c\}$ is not open, so $A := X \setminus \{c\}$ is not closed.  By the above, there is a point in $X \setminus A$ that is the limit of a sequence from $A$; the only point in $X \setminus A$ is $c$, so $c$ is the limit of a sequence from $X \setminus \{c\}$.

On the other hand, property ($*$) does not imply that the space is sequential.  Take $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology and consider $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{R}}$ with the product topology.  This space is not sequential (https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000101/properties?filter=sequential), so let us check that it has property ($*$).  No points in the space are isolated, so we take any $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$, and we want to find a sequence from $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{R}}\setminus\{f\}$ converging to $f$.  Recall that convergence in the product topology is pointwise convergence.  For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$ be defined by
$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}f(x) &\text{ if $x \not\in \mathbb{N}$ or $x < n$} \\ f(x)+1 &\text{ if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \geq n$}\end{cases}$

Then $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $f_n \to f$ in $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{R}}$, while clearly each $f_n \neq f$.